# How to round up timedelta by seconds?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to get time measurement of my script in format `HH:MM:SS`. `datetime.timedelta` does not have a `strftime` function. I want to get rid of the microsecond indication. `duration` is a `timedelta` object.

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.now()

for i in range(100000000):
    pass

end = datetime.datetime.now()

duration = end - start

print(duration)
```

Output:

```
0:00:03.474106
```

But I need:

```
0:00:04
```

Answer (score 1):

We take the duration (`timedelta` object) and subtract its own microseconds from itself, then store that in the variable `duration`.

```py
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.now()

for i in range(100000000):
    pass

end = datetime.datetime.now()

# duration = 0:00:03:962227
duration = end - start

# duration = 0:00:03:962227 - 0:00:00.962227
duration = duration - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=duration.microseconds)
# duration is now = 0:00:03

print(duration)
```

More information on `timedelta` and its arguments can be found at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to transform the end result `duration`. This way the time measurement might get skewed.

Comment: I updated the code so that the ms will only be removed from the duration result.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Sorry still new but I should have known anyways. I've updated the answer with the information.

Comment: OP asked for rounding of the microseconds. I don't see how this is an answer? 0:00:03.474106 does not round up to 0:00:03. It just gets rid of the microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the get rid of the milliseconds portion of the duration, you can use [floor division ('//')](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-does-double-slash-mean-in-python/) by a million and then multiply it back by a million:

```
print(duration // 1000000 * 1000000)
```

You can also create a new `timedelta` object from `duration` without the `milliseconds` attribute specified.

```
print(datetime.timedelta(duration.days, duration.seconds))
```

But if you want it to always round up instead, as suggested by the expected output of `0:00:04`, you can get the number of seconds from the `timedelta` object by calling the `total_seconds` methods, use `math.ceil` to round up, and then construct a new `timedelta` object with it:

```
import math
print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=math.ceil(duration.total_seconds())))
```